# Existence of a bounded continuous extension of a continuous function on a closed set.

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, functional-analysis, continuity, metric-spaces

For $X$ a metric space and $A\subset X$ closed, consider a function $f : A \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ that is continuous *and bounded*.

Tietze's extension theorem implies that $f$ admits a continuous extension to all of $X$, i.e. that

$$\tag{1}\text{there is a continuous} \quad F : X\rightarrow \mathbb{R} \quad \text{with} \quad F(a)=f(a) \quad \text{for all } a\in A.$$

**Question:** Can we choose the extension $F$ in $(1)$ such that it is also bounded? (References welcome.)

Comment: Yes and this is the important fact, for example if $f:A\to\mathbb{R}$ takes values in $[0,1]$, then $F$ can also be taken to take values in $[0,1]$, check out Folland's book for example, chapter 4.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Suppose $f(A)\subset [-M,M].$ Let $F$ be an extension of $f$ to all of $X.$ Define $g:\mathbb R \to [-M,M]$ by setting $g(y)=y$ for $y\in [-M,M],$ $g(y)=M$ for $y>M,$ and $g(y)=-M$ for $y<-M.$ Then $g\circ F$ does the job.